# Passing a value to a class from another class after event

Tags: c#, events, argument-passing

I got 2 windows that are not parents/children of each other and classes made for each once. Let's name them ClassA and ClassB. I am rising an event clicking button in ClassA. All i want to do is to pass variable from Class B after that button click and after that make one of ClassA functions to execute using that variable.

Comment: And what have you already tried?

Comment: i tried passing valuse by making instance of classB in classA and i managed to pass that variable. But problem is not solved, cause i can't just put that variable there, cause on first call to method it must have got certain value and i want to change it after some time and make method run.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without additional events by having an instance of the ClassB. You obviously need that instance unless it's a static class. You can pass the instance, for example, in a constructor or using a property.

```
public ClassA
{
    private ClassB classBInstance;

    public ClassA(ClassB classBInstance)
    {
        this.classBInstance = classBInstance;
    }

    void buttonClick(...)
    {
        classBInstance.SomeFunction(someVariable);
    }
}

public ClassB
{
    void SomeFunction(paramater)
    {
        mySecretVariable = parameter;
        CallAnotherMethodThatUsesThisVariable();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think u misunderstood my concept. I am trying to get variable from Class A into class B. I am clicking something in class A and after that click i want to rise method in class B.

Comment: You will need to create an event in ClassA, hold a reference to ClassA in ClassB, and attach a method in ClassB to the event firing from ClassA - Search for intros on creating Events first

Comment: @user3274820 I updated my answer. Can you do that like I'm suggesting? Can you get and instance of ClassB to ClassA and call a method with an argument directly? If not, I will suggest a solution using events.

Comment: That function can't use it as an argument. It uses that variable in the middle, but i can't pass that as variable. That click have to update my variable and later make method to execute.

Comment: I still do not see any problem. I once again updated my answer. Just pass the variable as an argument, update your local variable in the ClassB and then call another method that uses the variable.

Comment: That method is running first time at beggining of program using some variable. On the second run it should use passed variable. How can i check if that is the right moment to put my new variable into it and run function?

Comment: Use a bool flag. Something like `if (firstTime) then run this else run something else`.

Comment: Ok, i did all what u asked for. i change function to have argument. at the beggining of classA i am doing an instance of class B private classB instance;  and in button click:  instance.ReloadData(1);  . There is error: NullReference . When i am doing classB instance = new classB(); also nothing happens, but at least error is gone .

Comment: You have to send your instance of ClassB to an instance of ClassA to see something happen in the instance of ClassB you have. Check my answer. When creating an instance of ClassA, provide an instance of ClassB in a constructor and you will be fine.

Comment: That class has already 3 constructors, ok, made new with parameter of instance of another class. But it does not work cause it is using default constructor all the time. It crashes on that line: classBInstance.SomeFunction(someVariable); . And null reference again.     public classA()
        {} And another is public ClassA( int ID )
            : this()
        {}   when i am trying to change first constructor it is showing error with that another and this(). When i try to put something in it, nothing good happens.

Comment: If you can't solve such a problem, how do you expect to solve it using events? Even with events you have to pass an instance of something to somewhere in order get it working. If your complete code is not too long, post it here. Or post it somewhere else and I'll look at it and solve your problem for you.